# Get failed to include file php

Tags: php

I can use `get_included_files` to get an array with the names of included or required files.

However is there any way to get the list of files that are failing to get included?

Eg: some php file contains

```
include_once("abc.php");
```

on running it generates: `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I want to return the name of such files, in this case `"abc.php"`

Comment: can `get_last_error()` help?

Comment: Double check your "abc.php" is located at your root  where your index.php file exist.

Comment: if error logging's turned on such failures will be logged to a file (/var/log/php_error on this machine).  Try grepping that.

Comment: Sure `abc.php file` and `included main file` paths

Comment: it can work but then its there can be other errors too.. right? @Raptor

Comment: create a function that will check if a file is existing.. else store that file in an array.. so you can retrieve it back

Comment: Linux or Linux like operating system file names are CASE-SENSITIVE, so if your file name is "Abc.php", then your file would not be found...

Comment: how can i get the list of all the files that are included? despite being loaded correctly or not? Also im skeptical about doing regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an own error handler with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php) and in the function/method check for the desired error message and do some stuff with it.

```
<?php

// We want to see all errors of any type
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Set our own error handler to catch E_WARNING errors
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    // Strip out these warnings because an invalid include throws two warnings
    if(strpos($errstr, 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory') !== false)
        return true;

    // Extract the file name out of the warning message string
    if(preg_match('/Failed opening \'(.+?)\'/', $errstr, $matches) !== 1)
        return false;

    $rscFile = $matches[1];

    echo 'file include not possible: ' . $rscFile . '<br>';
    return true;
}, E_WARNING);

// Generate some errors
include_once('no-file-1.php');
include_once ('no-file-2.php');
include_once 'no-file-3.php';
include('no-file-4.php');
include 'no-file-5.php';
include ('no-file-6.php');

$arr = array('apple');

array_pop(array_shift($arr), 5);

echo $noVar;

require 'afile.php';
```

Comment: its handling the error correctly, however i need to get the name of the file that was failing. Im still not able to get that.

Comment: You can access the file name with a bit of regex. It's included in the `$errstr` var.

Comment: I optimized my code so that only the warnings get treeted which we want to custom handle. Every other warning goes back to the default PHP error handler.